# How to open multiple Python shells via IDLE on mac?

Tags: macos, python

On my Windows 7 machine, I often run multiple Python shells at a time. This is especially helpful when testing socket servers over `localhost`.

**How would I run multiple Python shells via IDLE on my Mac (running OSX 10.7.5).**

**EDIT**

I want it to be seamless - is it possible to make it so that each time I run a new script in idle, it opens a new instance instead of stopping the existing shell? `idle &` *does not work*

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal.app and enter `idle &` at the prompt whenever you want to open a new instance. The `&` runs the process in the background and returns you back to the shell prompt.

Comment: That opens a new shell, but it is disconnected from the terminal.

Comment: @vonbrand - right. That's what the OP is asking - how to open multiple IDLE windows.